# Desperately need help. why search and categories stopped working?

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch, search

Just to be clear: I have already tried flushing cache, compiler, reindexing, etc and the issue persists, same happens with default theme and both default and rwd packages. My other store works fine with identical config, 1.9.2.

Issue: search & categories results 0 results, even though there are results and it is somewhat working.

Category: https://www.airyhair.com/hair-samples-accessories.html

Search for "hair": https://www.airyhair.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=hair

As you can see, while it does not list any items, it finds them as typing "ggg" gives NO RESULTS error.

https://www.airyhair.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=ggg

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, advanced search does return the number of items found

https://www.airyhair.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=hair&description=&short_description=&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the third party module, which is nuts. I have had disabled two module parts that I was not using: Magestore_AffiliateplusReferFriend Magestore_Affiliatepluscoup After enabling, all is working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got it working, I can see those products coming up when searching, "hair."

It does sound related to the indexing, though.

Are there any errors in the var/log/system.log, exception.log, or any recent files in var/report?

The most common indexing problems I see are either timeouts (PHP max_execution_time) or perhaps MySQL is dropping the connection if your max_allowed_packet is too low.

You might have more luck using the command line indexing tool:

```
cd <your-documentroot>/shell
php indexer.php reindexall
```

I wrote a couple of articles on this topic - here's some further reading to rule out indexing as a problem:

http://blog.parsons.pw/is-magento-indexing-breaking-my-site/

http://blog.parsons.pw/foolproof-magento-indexing/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the product, Change **`Visibility`** from *`catalog`* to *`catalog, search`*

Comment: All are set to catalog, search and it was working fine before, no idea what has changed, same for all language stores.